# We are using a performance tool named Dynatrace and its throws error for if It is looking for some url http://localhost:631 for Birt reports

Tags: birt, dynatrace

In My organization we are using a performance tracking tool named Dynatrace,
Which says there are some errors when we open BIRT reports, i am not getting any idea from where this tool is hunting down this below issue.
It looks like it is looking for some url http://localhost:631 on calling /SLE_BIRT/frameset
and source of error is shown as org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl. Method is getUpdatedObjects().

Is BIRT is trying to access some kind of Web Service from its library.

Answer (score 1):

BIRT usually uses Apache Tomcat http://tomcat.apache.org/ as the web server when creating reports that run as HTML.  If you do not have Apache or another application correctly configured, you will get errors when trying to open BIRT reports with a URL.